# Generalized way of solving this types of equations $x^3 +y^4 =z^5$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$x^3 +y^4 =z^5$$
How can I solve this equation.I only know trial and error method, but it's not a generalized way.
Please tell me a generic way to solve this type of equation.

Comment: When you say "solve", do you mean find solutions that are real numbers, integer numbers or rational numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation $x^3 + y^4 = z^5$ has infinitely many solutions in positive integers. An infinite family of solutions is generated by
$$x = a(a^3 + b^4)^{8k},\qquad y=b(a^3 + b^4)^{6k},\qquad z=(a^3 + b^4)^{5k}.$$
There are probably other solutions; I doubt that an exhaustive list of solutions is known.

Beal's conjecture would imply that the equation has no relatively prime integer solutions. But this conjecture remains unproved, and there is a $1 million prize for a proof or counterexample.

Answer (score -1):

$$2^{24} +2^{24}=2^{25}$$
$$(2^{8})^{3} + (2^{6})^{4}=(2^{5})^{5}$$
So,$$ x=256\ ,\ y=64 \ ,\ z=32$$

Comment: I need a Generalized way .

Comment: Not an exact answer .

Comment: sorry don't know